# Compilar para uma plataforma inferior usando a ultima API?

Tags: android, apache-cordova, visual-studio

Estou utilizando o Cordova no Visual Studio 2017, e instalei a SDK do Android (API nível 23), porém gostaria de saber se ao compilar utilizando esta API, o aplicativo será compatível com versões anteriores, como o Android 4.2 por exemplo.

Até o ponto que eu saiba, não estou utilizando nenhum recurso específico da API 23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para definir a versão mínima do SDK, você precisa entrar nas configurações do Cordova e especificar o valor do level no qual deseja ser usado. Verifique o arquivo `config.xml` localizado na raiz do seu projeto. Veja abaixo como deve ficar caso você queira que seja compatível com Android 4.2, que neste caso é API Level 17:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="17" />
```

Veja mais detalhes [na documentação](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/).